# AngularJS (text) sliders?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a text slider (carousel), that will slide through array of text values. 
I've seen some implementations in bootstrap ui for angular, but they require an image to be present in order to work.
I found this, which is perfect (http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation), however, there is no source code or a how-to for implementation of this slider.
Are there any others available? Or is there a source code for this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this one:

[Build a Sweet Photo Slider with AngularJS Animate](http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-photo-slider-angularjs-animate/)

A step-by-step to create the component is provided.

Comment: From what I was able to see, this solution requires an image to be part of the carousel, otherwise it will not work - this is the same issue I have with bootstrap UI. I might be wrong, though. The problem is, I have no images in the content I want to rotate, just plain text.

Comment: I tried to use jquery with angular, but got the following issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666580/angularjs-ngrepeat-and-jquery-dom-rebuilding-issues

Answer (score 1):

For text only in the carousel, you may use Bootstrap carousel. You can use it in your angularjs application. Below is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lfrrrwa/2/)

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="carousel-content">text 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-content">text 2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```