# AngularJS ngRepeat and jQuery - DOM rebuilding issues

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am very well aware how mixing angularjs and jquery is NOT a good idea.
However, I need a custom carousel, which could slide through TEXT ONLY. All the existing carousel animations for angularjs depend heavily on image being part of the content, whereas I have no images.
So I found a very good jquery library for such a thing, called "slick".

It works well with angularjs, but when I dynamically ADD new values to an existing array, the whole thing breaks apart.
How could I change this part of code so that I could dynamically add objects to array AND keep jquery slick library working?

Here's the code, you can press "prev" and "next" and carousel will work, but as soon as you press ADD NEW ELEMENT button, the whole thing falls apart.
http://jsbin.com/tihodihuho/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Using directives for binding slick and unslick will be good idea.

Comment: Senthil I am very much interested in solving this with directives, however, I lack the proper knowledge. Do you have an example perhaps? Thank you. My current code: http://jsbin.com/yocun/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I can help you definitely, in middle of something now. I will add answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that by the time your call the jQuery functions `unslick` and `slick` the DOM has already been rendered.

You can accomplish that by having those functions inside a `$timeout` function (with delay 0, of course). That will ensure that the code inside the `$timeout` function will get executed after the `$diggest` cycle has finished.

Try this:

## [Example](http://jsbin.com/yajemafati/2/edit)

```
controller('myCtrl', ['$timeout',function($timeout){ 
  var self = this;  
  self.data = [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'A title, representing part 1',
        text: 'This is my TEXT 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Anoter interesting title that will grab your attention',
        text:'...and even longer text!'
      }];

  self.next =function() {
    $('.your-class').slickNext();
  };

  self.prev =function() {
    $('.your-class').slickPrev();
  };

  self.add = function() {
    var newID = self.data.length + 1;
    self.data.push({
      id:newID,
      title:'A totally new object!',
      text:'Dynamically added object to an existing array.'
    });   
    $timeout(function(){      
      $('.your-class').unslick();
       $('.your-class').slick({
        autoplay: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        swipeToSlide: true
      });            
    });
  };
}]);
```

## UDATE

In order to fix the issue that the OP described in the comments bellow, and that it's completely unrelated with the original question I've came up with this workaround:

```
$timeout(function(){            
  $('.your-class').unslick();

  //You would think that `unslick` would take care of this, but it didn't so: 
  $('.your-class .slick-cloned, .your-class .slick-list.draggable').remove();

  //this is a workaround, which proves that the issue was with the plugin
  //nothing to do with the original question. In order to address this properly the
  //OP should open a new question or a bug in the `unslick` plugin.

   $('.your-class').slick({
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 1500,
    swipeToSlide: true
  });            
});
```

## [Example](http://jsbin.com/wogeraluqo/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: While this DOES solve the problem, it creates a new one. For reasons unknown, each time I add new object to array, another empty div gets created in slick. However, the array is the correct size. For example, there are 2 objects in array and slick has two divs in carousel. Then I add another objects, there are 3 objects in array, but slick adds two divs (one empty) to its carousel. E.g.: http://jsbin.com/yocun/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @uglycode welcome to stackoverflow! Since this answer solves the original question you should mark it as accepted. The problem that you are having is generated by the `slick` plugin, and it's a completely different issue. Therefore, you should open a new question for that issue. This is how stackoverflow works, so please mark this answer as accepted, open a new question and I will be happy to help you there. Thanks!

Comment: @uglycode have a look at my latest update. However, be aware that this is not how SO works. Please mark this answer as accepted, thanks!

Comment: thank you for your explanation of the rules on SO and your suggested solution! If I understand correctly: creating new empty DIV is part of the bug in slick library?

Comment: @uglycode you're very welcome! No, the bug is that the `unslick` function is not removing the elements generated by the `slick` function. That's why I'm removing them manually in this line: `$('.your-class .slick-cloned, .your-class .slick-list.draggable').remove();` before making the new call to the `slick` function. I hope that helps.

Comment: @uglycode you should seriously consider to open a new question for this issue, there could be people who know better than I who this plugin works. I had a quick look to their documentation and in theory the `unslick` function should be removing those items.

Comment: Oh, I see! I understand now, unslick function therefore is buggy. Feel free to report the issue on github, if you have an account (I don't unfortunately): https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues
Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @uglycode will do it as soon as I get home! I'm glad that I was able to help you!